# IBM MQ hosted in Azure vm is not accessible via Logic App MQ connector

Tags: ibm-mq, azure-logic-apps

I have received connection details of IBM MQ server hosted in Azure VM. We are using logic Apps(in non-Integration Service Environment) and trying to connect to MQ using the MQ connector provided in Logic apps. However we have received only name(e.g. MQUSER) for Connect as field(as MQ team has not set any credentials for the user). Also all ports are enabled for in the VM (both inbound and outbound rules).
Still we are not able to successfully connect to MQ with Logic Apps and receiving error as "Could not connect to the target Host/Port" while creating the connection.

Currently I am trying to create Integration Service Environment and use Logic app connector from there, but is there any suggestions which can help to proceed in this issue? Edit: connection from ISE also didn't worked.

[image: connector-1]

[connector server name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBP4v.png)

EDIT:  Is there anyone who have hosted MQ in Azure VM and have worked on integrations in Azure? Does it need any kind of creation of specific role/authentication etc?
This is the MS doc which we are referencing for our work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-mq

Solution:  As of now we found that we need Data gateway setup(even if it is hosted in Azure VM) and certificate installation. So we have taken advantage of REST API endpoints for connecting to MQ and fetching the messages.
Now again as certificates are not installed at VM where MQ server is residing. We are using HTTP protocol to connect via Logic App.
suggested Url :
http://ip:9080/ibmmq/rest/v1/messaging/qmgr/QM1/queue/QUEUE1/message

Comment: I am not familiar with the application that you provide a screenshot of. What does the application expect to have in the field titled "Connection Name"? In MQ parlance this would be a host name and port number, but since you also have a field titled "Server" it is not clear to me what is expected in each field. I assume the contents of the field titled "Server" that you have blacked out are host name and port number? Are you able to TCP ping this host name?

Comment: The screenshot is of logic app MQ connector. Connection name is the name which we are giving for creation of this connection. Server we are providing ip:port.  Also we are not able to ping to the host as icmp port is blocked in the azure vm in which this MQ is hosted.

Comment: What is ISE mean?

Comment: Again, I don't know the "logic app", but in MQ parlance, I would expect IP address and port number to be specified as ip(port) not ip:port. It is possible that the "logic app" is converting it, but please double check what the "logic app" expects you to put in there. Also, if you cannot ping it, how can you be sure that the TCP/IP path to this server is available for MQ to connect to? Does your "logic app" write any other error details anywhere? If it is 'C' MQ app do you have an AMQERR01.LOG file to look in on your client machine?

Comment: ISE is integration service environment in Azure...which worked as isolated cloud environment.

Comment: In Logic app it is expecting as ip:host , I have added the snapshot. Can you share any idea about, If the MQ is hosted in Azure VM then what are the prerequisite for connectivity? I mean to ask does it need any specific role/authentication etc?

Comment: You said "as certificate are installed...We are using HTTP".  Did you mean "are not installed"?

Comment: You are right. Missed "not". Thanks for pointing this out :)